# Global NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, global-variables, nsmutablestring

I have a tabbed views where I need to select various options from different tabbed views which should be appended in the same string. For this I want to use a NSMutableString.

After all the options are selected and string is formed as required. I want to access this NSMutableString in the next view which is not tabbed. I think for this I need to declare the NSMutableString as a global variable?

Can someone please help me with this. I am new to objective-c and xcode. Thank you. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to have a singleton object, especially useful if you have more than just one variable you want shared.

Here's a good post about doing singletons right: http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html

Basically you'd have write a very simple class something like:

State.h:

```
@interface State : NSObject

@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableString *mystring;
+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

State.m:

```
#import "State.h"
@implementation State

@synthesize mystring;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
  static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
  __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
  });
  return _sharedObject;
}
@end
```

and then whenever you need it you could do:

```
import "State.h"

[State sharedInstance].mystring
```

Even simpler you can use singleton macro from here: https://gist.github.com/1057420#gistcomment-63896

I've personally found this pattern to be extremely useful.

Comment: do I need to import "State.h" where I use this?

Comment: oh right, yes in any class where you want to access `[State sharedInstance]` you need to `import "State.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can make it a property of your app delegate
2. You can use a singleton
3. You can use NSUserDefaults
4. You can arrange for all of the "interested party" objects to share some common object (with addressability passed during initialization) that contains a field pointing to your string

And probably several others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this:

**To save:**  (call before next view loaded in previous view class)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
[defaults setObject:yourString forKey:@"KEYNAMEHERE"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**To retrieve** (call when next view is loaded in the next view's class)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSMutableString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"KEYNAMEHERE"];
```

Comment: thanks! SO setobject:yourstring - where "yourstring" should be the variable name of NSMutableString type?

Comment: Yes, and KEYNAMEHERE is the name of a key (could be anything, just make it descriptive of what the object is, so maybe something like `globalString`).

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try this and get back to you!

Comment: Another question, can I use this for multiple mutablestrings in one tabbed view and retrieve all the variables in the next view?

Comment: Put the strings in an NSArray and put that where `yoursting` is in the code I've posted above.  Just keep track of the order the data is in.

Comment: This isn't really a good use of `NSUserDefaults`. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `NSUserDefaults` should be used for storing user preferences, not for other data. You should probably use a singleton or a static variable.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with static variables, which is why I didn't recommend it, also, everybody seems to dislike using singletons as "glorified global variables."  I recommended NSUserDefaults for a few reasons:  1.) It's extremely easy to use.  2.) If the asker wants to have this data persist and be used when the user starts the app (after the app is quit) he'll have to use either user defaults or core data or some other form of data persistance.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have 4 tabs, so ideally which method should this be called before changing the tab view? I am unable to determine that.